# Variable LDO implementation - capacitor size

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, ldo, linear

I am designing two linear power supplies that will:

1. Drop 9V DC to 5V DC to power a Raspberry Pi around 2.5A
2. Drop 9V DC to 7.5V DC to power a DAC under 3A

I plan to use [Texas Instruments LDO UCC283-ADJ](http://www.ti.com/product/ucc283). An adjustable LDO.

I have been reading the datasheet:

http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slus215

Which advises (see page 5) that a timing capacitor, C, is required:

> **CT**: Short-circuit timing capacitor and shutdown input for the UCC283−ADJ version. Pulling CT below 0.25 V
>   turns off the regulator and places it in a low quiescent-current mode. A timing capacitor, C, from CT to GND
>   programs the duration of the pulsed short-circuit on-time. On-time, t<sub>ON</sub>, is approximately given by:
>
> t<sub>ON</sub> = 750 k * C

Whilst the formula is given, I am at a loss as to what size capacitor I should use as C, for each of my implementations.

I was planning R1 to be 50kOhms and R2 to be 10kOhms.

Can anyone advise me on C?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at Eq (1) in the datasheet. The t_on you need depends how much capacitance is loading the regulator's output.

Comment: I just want to strongly recommend that you use a switching regulator.  You're using 49.5W input for 35W output, and the efficiency of everything in proximity to your linear regulators will be reduced because they are dissipating up to 15W as heat, making things worse.  If you desire the accuracy of an LDO linear regulator(For the Pi at least, a decent switching regulator should be more than accurate enough), consider using a switching regulator to drop most of the voltage and use the LDO just to chop off the last little bit.  Switch from 9 to 5.2V for example, then LDO from 5.2 to 5.

Comment: @KH it is also possible to make a Buck regulator using an LDO , FET, L , hysteresis comparator

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist thank you.  I'm just learning about switching regulator design right now, so I'm hardly the most informed.  Just hate to see someone burning off 15W when they could reclaim a lot of it with a $2 part.

Comment: All helpful and will consider this, but until I figure out how to setup the LDO I cannot really progress.

Comment: @KH how do you get 49.5w and 35w?

Comment: @ThPhoton equation I think refers to the output capacitor on VOut. I am stuck with the capacitor C on the CT pin. I think it is different.

Comment: @User32407 many LDOs are linear regulators.  Linear regulators drop voltage by wasting the extra voltage*output current, normally they are used because they are cheap, they drop out low and they can have an extremely linear output.  At maximum load, you'd have 5V*2.5A=12.5W and 7.5V*3A=22.5W, so a total of 35W output.  It will sometimes be less, but you have to plan for worst case.  Because linear regulators waste the extra voltage, you can multiply output current by input voltage to get the total power of 9V*5.5A=49.5W

Comment: @user32407 I'm just learning how to build switching regulators myself, so what I use LDOs for is providing a voltage reference at a tiny current at a low cost, and in this use they excel, saving me the trouble of learning parts knowledge about zener diodes when I'm trying to concentrate on other things.  They also see a lot of use in applications where the input voltage is very close to the output voltage because of the linearity of the output.

Comment: Just because you're mentioning 9V as your source, if you're planning to use rectangular 9V batteries, you should be aware that they, too are mostly suitable to a few specific applications (9V in small form factor at small currents)

Comment: I am actually planning to use 230v transformed down to 9v. Will look at ways to drop this to closer to 7.5v and 5.5v before LDO.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For the bypass cap on vout they say this:

> VOUT: Regulated output voltage. A bypass capacitor is not required at
> VOUT, but may be desired for good transient response. The bypass
> capacitor must not exceed a maximum value in order to insure the
> regulator can start.

They then say this:

> A capacitive load on the regulator’s output appears as a short-circuit
> during start-up. If the capacitance is too large, the output voltage
> does not come into regulation during the initial tON period and the
> UCC383 enters pulsed mode operation. The peak current limit, tON
> period, and load characteristics determine the maximum value of output
> capacitor that can be charged. For a constant current load the maximum
> output capacitance is given as follows:

$$ C_{out(max)} = (I_{CL}-I_{LOAD}\frac{t_{on}}{V_{out}} $$

So choose how long you want the part to turn on with the first equation, then calculate the maximum capacitance and choose a value of capacitance lower than Coutmax.

Comment: Thanks. I think that C on the CT pin which is where I am struggling and it is not the same as the Cout capacitor. For Cout using eq 1 ILoad I think is 2.5a L I assume is ILoad + 3a so 5.5a based on Pg5 "During an overload, the regulator
actively limits the maximum current to the peak current limit value. The peak current limit is nominally 3 A greater than the overcurrent threshold." VOut will be 5v. Ton unfortunately I have no idea, I know it is 750,000* C - but still no closer to determining C on the CT pin. Any help appreciated.